# Runnable Jar files only open with JDK

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

Every time i make a runnable jar file it only opens if the computer has JDK installed and will not run with just JRE, how can I make it run with only JRE?

Comment: Exactly what is the error message you get when running on the JRE?

Comment: @user1071777 "A Java Exeption Has Occured"

Comment: What is the full message?

Answer (score 1):

Your question makes little sense. You install the JRE, and verify that Java works at the command line:

```
java -version
```

If the above does not work, then the JRE is not installed correctly. If the above outputs the version you expect then you,

```
java -jar myfile.jar
```

If the above does not work, update your question with the error it displays.

Comment: Turns out I was building with java 8 instead of 7.